# ¿Cómo se llama el símbolo ‒́?

Tags: puntuación, dle

Acabo de toparme con una entrada la mar de curiosa en el diccionario de la RAE:

> **[‒́cola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9iwVE2n)**
>
> Del lat. *-cŏla*, de la raíz de *colĕre* 'cultivar', 'habitar'.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'que cultiva o cría' o 'que habita en'. *Avícola, frutícola, arborícola, cavernícola.*

Lo que más me ha llamado la atención es el signo **‒́**, que representa que el sufijo debe ir precedido obligatoriamente por una vocal acentuada. ¿Existe realmente este signo en el idioma español? ¿Qué nombre tiene? ¿Se usa en algún otro ámbito?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recién me entero de la existencia de ese signo, el cual no parece tener un nombre particular, pero parece que es lo que manda la RAE, según consigna el *[Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=guion)*:

> **3.2.1.** Se escribe un guion delante de un segmento de palabra (sílaba, morfema, elemento compositivo, etc.) para indicar que va en
>   posición final: *-illo*, *-idad*, *-ar*. En este caso, si a la sílaba
>   que precede a dicho segmento le corresponde llevar tilde, esta se
>   colocará sobre el guion: *-´fago* (litófago).

Deduzco que se llamará, meramente, "guion con tilde". De hecho, así se lo llama en [Wikilengua](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ida), en las pocas ocasiones en las que aparece. Cabe preguntarse desde cuándo manda la RAE acentuar el guion en estos casos.

Comment: Ahí está la clave: no tiene nombre, porque en realidad son dos signos: *Guión con tilde*.

Comment: Esto da casi para pregunta de Trivial: si nos preguntan sobre qué símbolos se puede colocar una tilde (´) en español ya sabemos que además de las vocales se puede colocar sobre un guion.

Comment: La tilde se puede colocar sobre un guion, pero no sobre la palabra _guion_.

Comment: @Rodrigo Pueees… ǵūìōń? O tal vez gu͡ɪo͜n? :-þ

Comment: @Rodrigo mientras la RAE tenga publicadas reglas [contradictorias](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=guion) me reservo el derecho de escribir como me parece más razonable ;)

Comment: @Rafael Yo la escribo con tilde (soy chileno y siento dos sílabas). Cuando vi la respuesta de JMVanPelt pensé que sin tilde era error, así que lo busqué en el diccionario y me di cuenta de que yo era el equivocado. Por eso puse mi comentario. Perdona si pareció que te estaba corrigiendo, de hecho no me di cuenta de que tú lo tenías con tilde. Y gracias por la referencia.

Comment: @Rafael De hecho, el signo que figura en la definición citada por el OP son dos caracteres Unicode y no un único signo. Lo mismo en la cita del DPD de la respuesta, es un guion seguido de una tilde.